# How to add array elements to object array as key value pair

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects

[I want to add key value pair to object array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2j7G.png)

[from this array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5WTb.png)

final array should have uniqueIds

```
const characters = [
{
name: "Luke Skywalker",
height: "172",
mass: "77",
eye_color: "blue",
gender: "male",
},
{
name: "Darth Vader",
height: "202",
mass: "136",
eye_color: "yellow",
gender: "male",
},
{
name: "Leia Organa",
height: "150",
mass: "49",
eye_color: "brown",
gender: "female",
},
{
name: "Anakin Skywalker",
height: "188",
mass: "84",
eye_color: "blue",
gender: "male",
},
];
```

```
att = ["B0117", "B5019", "B0821", "B0098"\];
attArr = characters.map((tim) => {
return { ...tim, UniqueId: "B0117" }
});
console.log(attArr);
```

i want to add elements from array(att) as uniqueID into the object array

```
name: 'Anakin Skywalker',
height: '188',
mass: '84',
eye_color: 'blue',
gender: 'male',
UniqueId: 'B0117'
```

all four elements should be mapped to UniqueID
uniqueId should have values from array.

> i want to insert that as key value pair[(https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
att = ["B0117", "B5019", "B0821", "B0098"];
attArr = characters.map((tim) => {
  return { ...tim, UniqueId: "B0117" }
});
console.log(attArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, you just need to pass index to `att` arr i. e `att[index]`

```
const attArr = characters.map((character, index) => {
  return { ...character, UniqueId: att[index] };
});

console.log(attArr);
```

The code will assign the unique IDs in the following manner:

- The first character in attArr will have a UniqueId of "B0117" because
  att[0] is "B0117".
- The second character in attArr will have a
  UniqueId of "B5019" because att[1] is "B5019" And so on,